# Referring to non-widget objects in Dojo without "polluting" global namespace

Tags: javascript, dojo, global-variables

What's a clean best practice for keeping track of and referring to general JavaScript objects - most likely Dojo-declared - that may have been declared in one area (read module) of an application but that need to be used in another area? We're assuming AMD here.

As mentioned by the "Non-Widgets" section of Dojo's ["Using Declarative Syntax" reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/declarative/):

> ... regular objects don't have a registry like Dijit based widgets do, therefore in order to be able to reference them after you instantiate them, you have to create a reference to them in the global scope.

Global scope? Rrraaughh?! One of the biggest things about ["Modern Dojo"](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/modern_dojo/) is the frowning upon willy-nilly usage of the global namespace:

> One of the core concepts of "modern" Dojo is that things in the global namespace are bad. There are numerous reasons for this, but in a complex web application, the global namespace can easily become polluted with all manner of code [...]. This means in "modern" Dojo, if you are about to access something in the global namespace **STOP** because you are doing something wrong.

Also, from that guide:

> Again, repeat after me "the global namespace is bad, the global namespace is bad, I will not use the global namespace, I will not use the global namespace".

In light of that, have there been any other popular ideas expressed about maybe having a general-purpose object registry that exists in the application's context? Is it feasible or perhaps obvious to just Dojo-define a module whose sole purpose is to be a mixed bag of references to objects that get used throughout the application?

Comment: There are plenty of ways to avoid global scope. It would be helpful if you would provide an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I just want a convenient way to interact with certain objects in my application through the console. I frequently type `widget = dijit.byId("<some_widget_id>")` and then read/write properties of that `widget` on the fly. Because `dijit.registry` can be accessed from the globally accessible `dijit` object (for now), it's super easy to play around with the widgets "stored" there. I'm looking for a clean way to allow certain non-widget objects of interest to be easily referenced, whether the referencing code is elsewhere in the application or in the console. I anticipate some use of require().

Comment: In that case, create a dojo module which hashes objects. Whenever you create an element add it to that module. Then you can retrieve it with something like dijit.byId("my_hash_0").get("customobject")